# SQL Server left outer ignores the record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can some one please help me in the below load?

I get a file daily and load it using SSIS and SQL.

File date 05/08/2018:

```
Date        product_name  Net_units 
01/08/2018  T1            8
```

File date 06/08/2018:

```
Date        product_name  Net_units 
01/08/2018  T1            18
```

File date 07/08/2018:

```
Date        product_name  Net_units 
01/08/2018  T1            24
```

Below is my query to load this organic data file:

```
insert into pdct_fact 
    select * 
    from staging_temp st
    left outer join pdct_fact ft on st.date = ft.date
                                 and st.product_name = ft.product_name
```

Since this record has been inserted on 06/08/2018 with the net_unit 0f 18, it got ignore on 07/08/2018 load and the net_units remains 18 and it should supposed to update the net_units as 24 in the pdct_fact with the latest record.

Any help on this please? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Updated the section with the table

Comment: The query you gave is unlikely to run at all. You're selecting all columns (`*`) from `staging_temp` and `pdct_fact` joined into `pdct_fact`. The join will add more columns to the result than `pdct_fact` has. That query should throw a "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition." error.

Comment: Sorry I just removed the column name
insert into pdct_fact Select 
st.date,
st.product_name from 
staging_temp st
left outer join 
pdct_fact ft
on st.date= ft.date
and st.product_name =ft.product_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a merge and set your fact table units equal to your staging table units when matched.  See below.

```
MERGE INTO pdct_fact ft
USING staging_temp st
    ON ft.date = st.date and ft.product_name = st.product_name
    WHEN MATCHED 
     THEN
       UPDATE SET 
           ft.net_units = st.net_units
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for this, i am getting below error     The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows

Comment: @MSM I was assuming the date and product name formed a unique natural key.  If that isn't the case, and you have duplicates in your table, does it even make sense to update them in the first place? Just append the rows if you're tracking the historical values in that table.  If not, remove the duplicates first and then do the merge i mentioned above.